# Log to a txt file from a Windows 10 Kernel Mode driver

Tags: c, logging, linker, windows-kernel

I am looking to do some logging from a Windows 10 Kernel mode driver (C). I have lots of logging inside the driver however in this instance I can't attach a kernel debugger so I would like to dump the debug strings to a txt file (or event log even).

Eg here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
VOID Log(char * text) {
    FILE *f = fopen("c:\\temp\\logger.txt", "a+");
    if (f == NULL) return;

    fprintf(f, "%s\n", text);

    fclose(f);
}
```

However I get

> ```
> driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fclose referenced in function Log
> driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fopen referenced in function Log
> tdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fprintf referenced in function Log
> ```

I've included stdio.h, is there something else I have to do to get this linked?

Or is because this is a kernel driver I cannot use these libraries and must perform a different low level procedure to write to a log file?

**edit: It appears I can't use fopen from a kernel driver.**

I tried this, however nothing gets written to the file. I based the code on this example:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/891805/how-to-open-a-file-from-a-kernel-mode-device-driver-and-how-to-read-fr

All I changed was setting the flag to FILE_OPEN_IF to append the file if it already exists. I know that opening and closing the handle everytime is very inefficient however I am simply testing right now.

```
VOID Log(char* text) {

    UNICODE_STRING     uniName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  objAttr;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\SystemRoot\\example.txt");  // or L"\\SystemRoot\\example.txt"
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, &uniName,
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
        NULL, NULL);

    HANDLE   handle;
    NTSTATUS ntstatus;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK    ioStatusBlock;

    // Do not try to perform any file operations at higher IRQL levels.
    // Instead, you may use a work item or a system worker thread to perform file operations.

    if (KeGetCurrentIrql() != PASSIVE_LEVEL) return;
        //return STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_STATE;

    ntstatus = ZwCreateFile(&handle,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock, NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0,
        FILE_OPEN_IF,
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
        NULL, 0);

    CHAR     buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t  cb;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
        ntstatus = RtlStringCbPrintfA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), text, 0x0);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
            ntstatus = RtlStringCbLengthA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &cb);
            if (NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
                ntstatus = ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock,
                    buffer, (ULONG)cb, NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
        ZwClose(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: `RtlStringCbPrintfA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), text, 0x0);` `text` is  formatting directives ?! obvious that not and your code wrong. also you need not every time open/close file but do this once

Comment: If you're going to develop for kernel-mode, you should get setup to debug kernel-mode.  Then use the debugger to step through this routine and see what happens.  Also you can use DbgPrint()/DbgPrintEx() to write to the debug output stream; you could write a message whenever something unexpected happens, like `(KeGetCurrentIrql() != PASSIVE_LEVEL)` or `!NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)`.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint  (Note the Remarks!)  This util lets you view the output: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview

Comment: Consider checking the IRQL first-thing, so you don't waste time initializing the UNICODE_STRING and OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES you might not use.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've been using the debugger and dbgprintex successfully.

Comment: Debug buffer is slow. I'd also advise to go with ETW / WPP. There _are_ in fact libraries out there trying to pretend that there is a full C runtime available in kernel mode. But it's a bad idea. Do't do it. So many things depend on stuff like IRQL (see @asynchronos's comment) and many more things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need to do logging from a kernel mode driver, I recommend that you look into WMI/WPP tracing. This will be able to log fast enough that it can keep up with most kernel events, which loging to a file or the debugger is not great for. It will also allow you to have tracing in your production/release driver without impacting performance so that you can enable customers to gather the logs and you can analyze them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing

Comment: Although the problem is solved this is a great answer.